# how to automatically rotate web game in mobile/tab etc

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am building a web game. now, I want to automatically rotate phone screen when visited by mobile. any suggestion.?
I tried this CSS below but that also didn't work

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  html {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
    width: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Please give me a suggestion by which the screen will automatically rotate when it's opened in mobile.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation You search this, but care, not work in some browsers. https://caniuse.com/#search=Screen%20Orientation

Answer (score 0):

Try

```css
body{
     margin:0;
     overflow:hidden;
   }

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: landscape) {
        .wrapper{
            transform: rotate(90deg);
            transform-origin:bottom left;
            position:absolute;
            top:-100vw;
            height:100vw;
            width:100vh;
            font-weight: 600;
        }
        }
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed porta, orci id porttitor convallis, odio dolor hendrerit mi, nec vestibulum ipsum est et nulla. Nam elementum mi eget arcu scelerisque congue. Proin eros magna, condimentum sed interdum nec, tristique in turpis. Mauris vulputate
        </p>
        <hr />
        <div>
        <a href="google.com" target='_blank'>Google</a>
        </div>
        <p>Rotate 90 degree</p>
        <hr />
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQjhOBG4ztvrvf0Jw6p_J3lMhnnKZ4TupbpIDVNy9OM38skvpi4" />
    </div>
```